# Python2 regular expressions seem faulty

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7.3 on Linux. Here is a shell session verbatim.

```
>>> f = open("feed.xml")
>>> text = f.read()
>>> import re
>>> regexp1 = re.compile(r'</?item>')
>>> regexp2 = re.compile(r'<item>.*</item>')
>>> regexp1.findall(text)
['<item>', '</item>', '<item>', '</item>', '<item>', '</item>', '<item>', '</item>']
>>> regexp2.findall(text)
[]
```

Is this a bug, or is there something I'm not understanding about Python regular expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, '.' does not match a newline. Try with

```
regexp2 = re.compile(r'<item>.*</item>', re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answer to this question: Don't use regular expressions to parse non-regular languages such as XML. [It drove one S-O user insane.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) [Another relevant link.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Comment: This doesn't address his misunderstanding of regular expressions, however.

Comment: A valid point, but I'm only using this code for a quick hack and thus don't want or need to learn any new APIs.

Comment: I finally followed the link to the insane S-O user. I'd retract my downvote for that if I could :)

Comment: @chepner: made a trivial (whitespace only) edit so you can retract the downvote.

Comment: @Jangler: quick hacks often become scripts that you rely on. if you learn the new API then you can do a quick hack with the new API